# Cakephp Fixtures automatic truncate table not working properly

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, truncate

I recently switched over from cakephp 2.2.5 to 2.3 and the auto-truncate table is no longer working in 2.3.

What I did in 2.2.5 was just testing the framework using some small tables with no relations aka foreign keys constraints and the fixture import and auto-truncate table worked flawlessly.

Until I confirmed that I wanted to use cakephp and started developing my application using the CakeTestCase again. It stopped working. Data is still in the test database after they are imported the first time. So second time it would indicate that it fails to auto-load fixtures because data with the same IDs already exist.

So I started to suspect that it was mainly because the foreign key constraints I had in my current tables.

I searched the web and noticed that quite a lot of people having the same issue but there isn't a real solution to it yet.

The only one that seems to be a solution is here:
http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2905-tests-fixture-table-ar-not-truncate-when-droptable-false

However, I tried turning on $dropTables = true, it didn't work. And also I tried modifying the CakeFixtureManager.php as suggested and it didn't work either.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?